# Transients and periods of an idempotent function

Tags: functions

We write $[ n ] = \{ 1,2 ,\ldots, n \}$. Suppose we have function $f : [ n ] \rightarrow [ n ]$ such that $f$ is idempotent. Which are the transients $t$ and periods $p$?

1. $t\leq 1$ and $p=1$
2. $t>0$ and $p>0$
3. $t>0$ and $p=1$
4. $t=0$ and $p=1$

I thought that it should be $t>0$ and $p> 0$ because the function can have multiple periods $p$, it doesn't have to be equal to $1$.
Apparently, this answer is incorrect. I do not know the correct answer. Please help me out here to understand how to approach this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please do try to familiarize yourself with MathJax and latex typesetting so that others do not have to keep formatting your questions for you. You should also keep the title relatively brief and put *all relevant aspects* of the problem in the body of the question (not just the title).

Comment: I'm sorry! I'll keep that in mind